# json data not making it back to client using angular and asp webmethod

Tags: asp.net, json, angularjs

Here is the angular http call:

```
$http({
        url: "SingleSNP30second.aspx/GetSummary",
        method: "POST",
        data: { summaryId: $scope.summaryId },
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
    });
```

Here is the asp web method:

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static List<SummaryInfoJson> GetSummary(int summaryId)
    {
        DeveloprodDataClassDataContext masterDb = new DeveloprodDataClassDataContext();
        List<SummaryInfoJson> Summaries = (from t in masterDb.tbl_thirty_second_summaries_single_snps
                            join g in masterDb.tbl_custom_SNP_Genotypes on t.GenotypeId equals g.GenotypeId_this
                            join v in masterDb.tbl_custom_SNP_Variants on t.VariantId equals v.SnpsVariantId_this
                            join s in masterDb.tbl_thirty_second_summaries_stop_light_colors on t.StopLightColorId equals s.StopLightColorId_this
                            join l in masterDb.tbl_thirty_second_summaries_levels_of_evidences on t.LevelOfEvidenceId equals l.LevelOfEvidenceId_this
                            join d in masterDb.tbl_custom_SNP_Drugs_Apelon_NUIs on t.DrugId equals d.SnpsDrugId_this
                            join m in masterDb.tbl_thiry_second_summaries_summary_states on t.SummaryStateId equals m.SummaryStateId_this
                            join u in masterDb.tbl_users on t.EntrantUserId equals u.userId_this
                            where t.OriginalSummaryId == summaryId
                            select new SummaryInfoJson
                                (
                                t.ThirtySecondSummaryId_this,
                                d.Drug,
                                v.Variant,
                                g.Genotype,
                                t.ThirtySecondSummary,
                                s.StopLightColor,
                                l.LevelOfEvidence,
                                u.userName,
                                m.SummaryState
                                )
                        ).ToList();
        return Summaries;
    }
```

Here is the defition of the SummaryInfoJson class:

```
[Serializable]
    public class SummaryInfoJson
    {
        int ThirtySecondSummaryId;
        string Drug {get; set;}
        string Variant {get; set;}
        string Genotype {get; set;}
        string ThirtySecondSummary { get; set; }
        string StopLightColor { get; set; }
        string LevelOfEvidence { get; set; }
        string UserName { get; set; }
        string SummaryState { get; set; }

        public SummaryInfoJson(int thirtySecondSummaryId, string drug, string variant, string genotype, string thirtySecondSummary, string stopLightColor,
            string levelOfEvidence, string userName, string summaryState)
        {
            this.ThirtySecondSummaryId = thirtySecondSummaryId;
            this.Drug = drug;
            this.Variant = variant;
            this.Genotype = genotype;
            this.ThirtySecondSummary = thirtySecondSummary;
            this.StopLightColor = stopLightColor;
            this.LevelOfEvidence = levelOfEvidence;
            this.UserName = userName;
            this.SummaryState = summaryState;
        }
    }
```

On debug I can see that the database call works and Summaries get initialized to a List of SummaryInfoJson objects. Somehow the http response does not contain the objects though, it is just an empty array...

I didn't include the definition of SummaryInfoJson as well as the database call to keep the code short. I can definitely provide them if you want.

Edit: Ok, I added the following to the webmethod:

```
string returnVar =  new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Summaries);
            return returnVar;
```

returnVar is blank. The error is in the serialization. Why is my list not being serialized? I added the serializable attribute to that class definition..

Comment: Have you tried to use Fiddler or some other tool to inspect the data being sent by your browser, and the return values from the server?

Comment: I am using the network tab on the google chrome developer. The response is a blank array but when I set a break point at "return summaries;", Summaries is an array of objects..

Comment: What happens if you navigate to the page directly in your browser?

Comment: When I type localhost/SingleSNP30second.aspx/GetSummary directly into my browser I get a version of localhost/SingleSNP30second.aspx in which angular is not running (binding expressions are not evaluated)

Comment: @Byc, are you missing any typecast, just to be sure, Change return type to , say, `string` and simply return `something`, see if still you are able to get that in `ang`

Comment: Hi Arindam, thanks for the response. Returning a string is working fine! Let me post the rest of the code (I will edit the original post). I just cannot figure out what is wrong

Comment: Make properties of SummaryInfoJson `public`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make your properties of SummaryInfoJson `public`, like

```
public class SummaryInfoJson
{
    public string Drug {get; set;}
    public string Variant {get; set;}
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I spent so much time on that. There should be some kind of error or something.

Comment: It isn't an error though - well other than a programmer errror :-)